# CDI DAO generic

Tags: java, generics, entity, dao

Здравствуйте.
Мне нужно написать generic dao используя именно CDI (не spring, не ejb). Но я не смог нагуглить адекватный ответ по этой теме. Вот, что у меня есть:

**GenericDAO interface**

```
public interface GenericDAO <T  extends Serializable> {

/**
 * Adds the given entity object to DB.
 *
 * @param newObject the object to add in DB.
 * @throws SQLException an exception that provides information
 *                      on a database access error or other errors.
 */
void add(T newObject) throws SQLException;

/**
 * Deletes the given object from DB.
 *
 * @param object object to delete.
 * @throws SQLException an exception that provides information
 * on a database access error or other errors.
 */
void delete(T object) throws SQLException;

/**
 * Selects all rows from DB table and returns objective representation
 * of these rows in list.
 *
 * @return list of all objects from DB table.
 * @throws SQLException an exception that provides information
 *                      on a database access error or other errors.
 */
List<T> findAll() throws SQLException;

/**
 * Selects a row with given id from DB table and returns its
 * objective representation.
 *
 * @param id the id of a row too look for.
 * @return entity object of selected row in DB table.
 * @throws SQLException an exception that provides information
 *                      on a database access error or other errors.
 */
T findById(long id) throws SQLException;

/**
 * Updates given object in DB.
 *
 * @param object the object to update.
 *
 * @throws SQLException an exception that provides information
 * on a database access error or other errors.
 */
void update(T object) throws SQLException;
```

}

**GenericDAOImpl abstract class**

```
public abstract class GenericDAOImpl<T extends Serializable>
    implements GenericDAO<T> {

protected Class<T> entityClass;

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public GenericDAOImpl(){
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public void add(T newObject) throws SQLException {
    entityManager.persist(newObject);
}

public void delete(T object) throws SQLException {
    entityManager.remove(object);
}

public List<T> findAll() throws SQLException {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
    Root<T> rootEntry = cq.from(entityClass);
    CriteriaQuery<T> all = cq.select(rootEntry);
    TypedQuery<T> allQuery = entityManager.createQuery(all);

    return allQuery.getResultList();
}

public T findById(long id) throws SQLException {
    return entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
}

public void update(T object) throws SQLException {
    entityManager.merge(object);
}
```

}

Ну и затем просто GenericDAOImpl наследуется классом с явно указанным типом (напр. ClientEntity). Так вот я не совсем понимаю, как тут использовать CDI, зачем нужен PersistenceContex и т.д. Да, сам проект сделан на Maven, деплой должен быть на Tomcat. Выразился скорее всего не точно, так что уточняйте. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кому пригодится:

Во-первых, вот примерно тот GenericDAO, что искал:
[CDI-GenericDAO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029827/cdi-genericdao-and-custom-implementations)

Но тем, кто мало знаком с CDI, будет сложно понять примеры. Поэтому [вот просто отличнейший мануал по CDI](https://dzone.com/articles/cdi-di-p1), отличается от большинства туториалов тем, что он адаптирован не для web проекта, а обычного maven проекта, где можно все запустить просто из метода main.

Для того, чтобы cdi заработал, вам нужен `beancontainer`. Тут не все так просто, но пользуйтесь source code для этого же туториала, в случае, если вы не деплоите приложение на сервер (обратите внимание на pom.xml):

http://jee6-cdi.googlecode.com/svn/tutorial/cdi-di-example/

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю, что ты имеешь ввиду спецификацию `CDI 1.1 (1.0)` из набора спецификаций `java-ee`.

Во-первых `tomcat` из коробки не поддерживает `CDI`, т.к. не является полноценным `java-ee`-сервером. Следовательно тебе надо внедрить `CDI`-движок (скорее всего `weld`) либо в приложение либо в tomcat. Простейший пример [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995951/how-to-install-and-use-cdi-on-tomcat).

Собственно `CDI` по функциональным возможностям напоминает `Spring DI`. Вместо `@Autowired` используется `@Inject`, вместо `@Component` используется `@Named` и т.д. Простейший пример (`@Named` не используется, т.к. реализация интерфейса одна).

```
public inteface IService<T>
{
  T get();
}

public class TestPojo
{
}

//@Named
public class TestService implement IService<TestPojo>
{
 public TestPojo get()
  {
  returb new TestPojo();
  }
}

//Это компонент, в который внедряется другой компонент
public class TestInject
{
@Inject
private IService<TestPojo> service
//....
}
```

Для более точного ответа напиши больше информации.

**UPDATE:**

`@PersistanceContex` относится к спецификации `JPA`, которая некоим образом (кроме встроенных возможностей внедрения) не пересекается с `CDI`. [Ссылка для ознакомления](http://alextretyakov.blogspot.ru/2013/06/osnovy-jpa-i-hibernate.html). Сама аннотация `@PersistanceContex` это своего рода `@Inject` для экземпляра класса, реализующего `EntityManager`. А `CDI` это штука, которая предполагает возможность умного внедрения (инициализации) полей объекта (их и помечают как @Inject) извне (контейнером). Умного, потому что ты можешь указать поле с типом какого-либо интерфейса, а `CDI` сам найдёт класс реализующий этот интерфейс и внедрит его, если таковой конечно имеется.

**CDI и базы данных, включая средства работы с ними в java (JDBC, JPA, JPQL и т.д.), никак друг на друга не завязаны.**

Comment: Да, вы все верно поняли и уже сильно помогли, но я не до конца понимаю работу CDI. Сформулировать вопрос тоже сложно, т.к. совсем новая тема для меня. Смотрите, что вообще нужно. Есть много сущностей для БД, есть вот такой абстрактный DAO класс, используя который я хочу сделать dao для каждой сущности (если это правильный путь?). К примеру, я достаю сущность из базы данных, затем, возможно, делаю DTO, и в итоге что-то показываю во View. И как тут использовать CDI? Зачем и как использовать PersistanceContex? Где использовать в моем случае @Inject? У меня задание такое - использовать CDI :(

Comment: @DmitrySoroka обновил ответ, но тут пока не попробуешь - не поймешь)

Comment: Хорошо, я попробовал использовать cdi по некоторым примерам, вроде вашего. Подключил weld, TomEE. Но, если смотреть на ваш пример, когда я допустим пытаюсь использовать `new TestInject().getService().get()`, то получаю NullPointer. Я думал, что `@Inject` сам создает и подставляет необходимы объект? И можете  простыми словами еще объяснить когда и для чего обычно CDI используется?:)

Comment: @dmitrysoroka приводи код твоего примера в отдельном вопросе